# How to compile Jenkins Pipeline Groovy locally?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Does anyone have the magic maven/gradle invocation to compile a set of jenkins pipeline DSL groovy files?

Comment: Do you mean interpret it for errors, locally?

Comment: Yes, that would be one use. Another use may be to add testing.

Comment: This is what I use personally: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter

Comment: This is only good for linting

Comment: I know about that, but it seems to only understand static constructs, and we have a lot of dynamic code (basically loops which generate whole sets of pipelines).

Comment: Maybe what you really want is to test your pipeline code locally? You may want to have a look into https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit or the JenkinsTestHarness: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-test-harness which actually is used by the Jenkins plugin and core developers.

Comment: I would like to check specifically for one error locally:
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

General error during class generation: Method code too large!`

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is not compiled (like C#), it is interpreted.

Depending on exactly what you are trying to test potential options are:

1. Jenkins Groovy Script Console under Manage Jenkins. Note: You will need to be an Admin to be able to access this.
2. Pipeline Syntax Generator. It is improving. Go to a build of Pipeline job and in the LHS menu you will see a 'Pipeline Syntax' link.  Some items require you to first select `Pipeline: Steps` from the first dropdown.

Comment: I wished there was a non-interactive method, usable as a pre-merge test.

Comment: In fact groovy is compiled into Java byte code which will be executed in the JVM.

Comment: @JoergS This is true, although Groovy behaves like many interpreted languages in that source files can be directly executed with the `groovy` command.